# Cannot decode complete cipher list in .NET SslStream handshake

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

While attempting to move from a 'C' based SSL implementation to C# using the .NET SslStream and we have run into what look like cipher compatibility issues with the .NET SslStream and a AS400 machine we are trying to connect to (which worked previously).

When we call SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient it is sending the following:

16 03 00 00 37 01 00 00 33 03 00 4d 2c 00 ee 99 4e 0c 5d 83 14 77 78 5c 0f d3 8f 8b d5 e6 b8 cd 61 0f 29 08 ab 75 03 f7 fa 7d 70 00 00 0c 00 05 00 0a 00 13 00 04 00 02 00 ff 01 00

Which decodes as (based on http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/ssl/draft302.txt)

```
[16] Record Type  
[03 00] SSL Version  
[00 37] Body length

[01] SSL3_MT_CLIENT_HELLO  
[00 00 33]  Length (51 bytes)

[03 00] Version number = 768  
[4d 2c  00 ee] 4 Bytes unix time  
[… ] 28 Bytes random number  
[00] Session number  
[00 0c] 12 bytes (2 * 6 Cyphers)?  
[00 05, 00 0a, 00 13, 00 04, 00 02, 00 ff] -> [RC4, PBE-MD5-DES, RSA, MD5, PKCS, ???]  
[01 00] Null compression method
```

The as400 server responds back with:

```
15 03 00 00 02 02 28

[15] SSL3_RT_ALERT  
[03 00] SSL Version  
[00 02] Body Length (2 Bytes)  

[02 28] 2 = SSL3_RT_FATAL, 40 = SSL3_AD_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE
```

I'm specifically looking to decode the '00 FF' at the end of the cyphers.
Have I decoded it correctly? What does, if anything, '00 FF' decode too?

I am using the following code to test/reproduce:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace TestSslStreamApp
{
    class DebugStream :
        Stream
    {
        private Stream AggregatedStream { get; set; }

        public DebugStream(Stream stream) { AggregatedStream = stream; }

        public override bool CanRead { get { return AggregatedStream.CanRead; } }
        public override bool CanSeek { get { return AggregatedStream.CanSeek; } }
        public override bool CanWrite { get { return AggregatedStream.CanWrite; } }
        public override void Flush() { AggregatedStream.Flush(); }
        public override long Length { get { return AggregatedStream.Length; } }

        public override long Position
        { 
            get { return AggregatedStream.Position; }
            set { AggregatedStream.Position = value; }
        }

        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            int bytesRead = AggregatedStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);

            return bytesRead;
        }

        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) { return AggregatedStream.Seek(offset, origin); }
        public override void SetLength(long value) { AggregatedStream.SetLength(value); }

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            AggregatedStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string HostName = "as400";

            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(HostName, 992);

            SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(new DebugStream(tcpClient.GetStream()), false, null, null,
                                                    EncryptionPolicy.AllowNoEncryption);

            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(HostName, null, SslProtocols.Ssl3, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source: [RFC 5746 TLS Renegotiation Extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5746)

```
3.3. Renegotiation Protection Request Signaling Cipher Suite Value

  Both the SSLv3 and TLS 1.0/TLS 1.1 specifications require
  implementations to ignore data following the ClientHello (i.e.,
  extensions) if they do not understand it.  However, some SSLv3 and
  TLS 1.0 implementations incorrectly fail the handshake in such a
  case.  This means that clients that offer the "renegotiation_info"
  extension may encounter handshake failures.  In order to enhance
  compatibility with such servers, this document defines a second
  signaling mechanism via a special Signaling Cipher Suite Value (SCSV)
  "TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV", with code point {0x00, 0xFF}.
  This SCSV is not a true cipher suite (it does not correspond to any
  valid set of algorithms) and cannot be negotiated.  Instead, it has
  the same semantics as an empty "renegotiation_info" extension, as
  described in the following sections.  Because SSLv3 and TLS
  implementations reliably ignore unknown cipher suites, the SCSV may
  be safely sent to any server.  The SCSV can also be included in the
  SSLv2 backward compatible CLIENT-HELLO (see Appendix E.2 of
  [RFC5246]).
```

Comment: Now that I know this I can move onto working out what the server will actually accept.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to check what is your C implementation sending, and see which SSL version and ciphersuites it requests, and, after all, see what server is responding with - SSL version and chosen ciphersuite.